# Random Forests versus Boosting - Different Distributions

Tags: machine-learning, distributions, random-forest, boosting

Trying to wrap my head around the impact of variables with different distributions on Random Forests versus Stochastic Gradient Boosting. Specifically:

-How would variables with long tails impact trees in random forests versus stochastic gradient boosting, and what might that mean for results?

-How would variables with truncated distributions impact trees in random forests versus stochastic gradient boosting, and what might that mean for results?